# MATLAB decimal places in array

Tags: matlab, find

Consider the following example:

```
Bathymetry = [0,4134066;
    3,3817906;
    6,3343666;
    9,2978725;
    12,2742092;
    14,2584337;
    16,2415355;
    18,2228054;
    20,2040753;
    23,1761373;
    26,1514085];

Depth = [0;1;2;3;5;8;10;11.6;15];

newDepth = min(Bathymetry(:,1)):0.1:max(Bathymetry(:,1));
```

From this I want to find which column of 'newDepth' corresponds to 'Depth'. For example:

```
dd = find(newDepth==Depth(1))
dd =

     1
```

Showing that Depth == 0, is located in the first column of newDepth. When I apply this to all of the entries of 'Depth'

```
for i = 1:length(Depth);
    dd(i) = find(newDepth == Depth(i));
end
```

I receive an error:

```
Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.
```

Initially I couldn't understand why, but by looking at the array for newDepth, especially column 117 where newDepth == 11.6, I noticed that the value isnt equal to 11.6 but equal to 11.600000000000001 thus being different from Depth(8). How can I fix this? and why does MATLAB not just write the value as 11.6? nowhere have I specified to include the .000000000000001.

Comment: The peculiarities of floating-point arithmetic are a regular source of questions here on SO.  I suggest you read a few of the Qs and As under the tag *floating-point* before you do anything else.  This is a very important topic for would-be computational scientists such as I divine you to be.  If you don't understand the perils and pitfalls the programs you write are likely to contain subtle errors which may not manifest themselves in crashes or error messages; they may wait until you've published your erroneous results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no exact representation of 0.1 in binary. Read [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system#Fractions_in_binary) for more background. In binary, representing `0.1` is something like trying to write out all the decimals of one-third:

```
1/3 == 0.333333333333333333...
```

it will never be exact, no matter how many `3`'s you add.

For this (and many other) reasons, I'd suggest you do not use `==` (which is a very stringent demand), but rather use

```
for ii = 1:length(Depth);
    [~,dd(ii)] = min( abs(newDepth-Depth(ii)) );
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is to to with floating point arithmetic which is quite complicated, i recommend you google it and read a bit, there is plenty out there explaining it. Here is a good start: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/23/a-glimpse-into-floating-point-accuracy/

To solve it for your case I would suggest rounding

```
newDepth = round(newDepth * 10) / 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The 11.600000000000001  is because the number 11.6 is not exactly representable in binary floating point notation. This is to do with the way the hardware works rather than any limitation of Matlab.

You want to change your compare to something like

```
dd(i) = find(abs(newDepth - Depth(i))<.0000001);
```